# Solving Recurrent Relations using Backtracking

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

The following formula has been provided:

$a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2)\quad \mbox{with initial states}\quad 0 , 2  $

After some research the formula is found to be a Binet's Formula.

It is required to convert the above recursive formula to an explicit formula using the Backtracking method.

This is what i have done:
\begin{align}
a(n) &= a(n-1) + a(n-2) = (a(n-2) + a(n-3)) + a(n-2)  
    \\ & = 2a(n-2) + a(n-3) = 2(a(n-3) + a(n-4)) + a(n-3)  
     \\ & = 3a(n-3) + 2a(n-4) = 3(a(n-4) + a(n-5)) + 2a(n-4)  
    \\ & = 5a(n-4) + 3a(n-5) = 5(a(n-5) + a(n-6)) + 3a(n-5)  
    \\ & = 8a(n-5) + 5a(n-6)
     \\ & \vdots
    \\ & \mbox{and so on}\ldots
\end{align}

As it can be seen, there is a relationship with Pascal triangle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If $a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) $, then $a(n)=a(1)F_n + a(0) F_{n-1}$,where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number. (Use $F_{-1}=1$.)

Here is a roadmap for a proof:

- Let $b(n)=a(1)F_n + a(0) F_{n-1}$.
- Prove that $b(n) = b(n-1) + b(n-2)$
- Prove that $b(1)=a(1)$ and $b(0)=a(0)$.
- Conclude that $b(n)=a(n)$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
It looks like
$a(n)
= b(k)a(n-k)+b(n-1)a(n-k-1)
$
for some sequence
$b(k)$.
Find the recurrence
satisfied by $b(k)$.

Then set $k=n-1$.